# Bad SATA cable suddenly? (MacBook Pro mid 2012)

Tags: macos, ssd, sata, kernel-panic

OS X 10.9.2

Story

- SSD crashed due to kernel panic (Crucial M4).
- Data was still on it when I plugged it in via USB.
- Wiped and tried to reinstall via Time Machine, extremely slow transfer rate (est. 100 hours for 90GB), restart computer.
- SSD won't mount anymore, which leads me to believe it's the SSD that has a hardware issue.
- Use 5400RPM backup HDD, use Time Machine to restore, transfer takes 1 hour for 90GB.
- Works but very stupid slow wake time from sleep (like 5 minutes) and other slow related weird stuff. I think maybe I'm too used to SSD speeds.
- Laptop is mission critical and can't wait to RMA SSD, get new SSD (Crucial M500), seems good, use CCC to copy OS on backup HDD, repair permissions and repair disk is clean.
- Put in new SSD, won't boot, blinking folder
- Removed new SSD. Put in backup HDD, won't boot, blinking folder.
- Removed backup HDD, put in new SSD, go into recovery mode, wipe it clean, fresh install OS, transfer rate seems legit.
- Download done, almost done Setup Assistant, but when I enter my computer user info at the last step it keeps looping back me back to step 1.
- Reboot computer, blinking folder, go to Disk Utility and says there's no data on it.
- Removed new SSD, put in backup HDD, blinking folder, reboot, backup HDD now works.
- Computer seems to be working fine with backup HDD for now.

DriveDx Reports

[image]

[image]

I'm confused as to why would the HDD work and not the SSD. I'm thinking maybe the cable can't handle SSD speeds and loses data, versus the 5400 is slower and doesn't lose data. Do you have any thoughts?

edit 23/03/2014

The 5400 HDD started getting the blinking folder problem too. My workaround was to shutdown and for some reason it would boot correctly afterwards. Today, I got the blinking folder 3 times and in a row. I decided to unplug/plug the battery and after it booted correctly. I'm still not sure whether this is SATA related. What does unplugging the battery actually clear? PRAM, NVRAM, both, none? Can't seem to find the info on Google.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your SSD is not in a "panic lock" mode.

Usually, when this is the case (at least on an OCZ Vertex 2), there is a red LED on, just beside the green LED, when you plug the SSD.

I still don't understand exactly what this "panic lock" is really, but the result is that the SSD cannot be accessed any more, only the manufacturer can unlock it.  It seems to happen after sleep and/or hibernation of computer using the SSD.